# выравнивание блоков div на bootsrap

Tags: html5, css3

есть вот такая [страничка](http://lptf.it/index.php?route=projects) с блоками (bootstrap), не получается их сделать ровными, т.е. чтоб они небыли как сейчас, как говориться в разноброс, а ровно упорядоченые.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать flexbox. Подробный гайд по ссылке -https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ Вам понадобятся свойства flex-direction, flex-grow, align-self, justify-content

Comment: спасибо большое, Вы помогли